# Custom Internet Explorer Security Settings

Tags: security, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set the highest security settings possible on Internet Explorer. These are the steps I've taken:

1. Set everything to high (Internet, local Internet, trusted sites, and restricted sites)
2. Added http://www.youtube.com to trusted sites.
3. Enabled the following ActiveX settings under trusted sites:

   - Allow only approved domains to use ActiveX without prompting
   - Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins

With this configuration (and Flash Player installed) I can view videos on YouTube. However, I'm unable to see the images for the suggested videos that run vertically along the right hand side of the page.

I've tried a few things to try and see these images, but am unable to identify the appropriate settings. Is anyone aware of what needs to be done to allow these images to be seen?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make YouTube's features to work correctly--including the suggested videos thumbnails--you will also have to add the domain ytimg.com to your trusted sites zone.